# Drupal 8: Debugging tests with XDebug and PHPStorm - cennot step through

Tags: php, drupal, phpunit, xdebug, drupal-8

I'm trying to debug my Drupal 8 tests with XDebug, but if I run them with XDebug switched on, I cannot step into the test. I execute the following command:

> vendor/bin/phpunit -c core
>   modules/permissions_by_term/tests/src/Kernel/SelectTermTest.php

PHPUnit reports me here:

> "Can't find a source position. Server name 'localhost' doesn't exist."

My settings in the PHP.ini file are looking as follows:

> xdebug.remote_enable=true xdebug.profiler_enable=0
>   xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM xdebug.max_nesting_level=256
>   xdebug.remote_autostart=true

Can anybody share here some experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to run. I had to do some more settings.

First, create a new PHP Remote Debug under the Run Configurations (The ZeroConfiguration didn't work for me). Define a Server with the name you want (here "TestServer") and enter PHPSTORM as Ide Key.

Also see the Jetbrains documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+Web+Applications+with+Run+Debug+Configurations

Enable the option "Break at first line in PHP scripts" in under the RUN menu .

It can be possible that you need to override the file mapping. (In my case PHPStorm is not able to detect file mapping automatically) (See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/override-server-path-mappings-dialog.html). It's is within same dialog where the server was created.

Start the Remote Debug Session with clicking on the corresponding icon.

Then you should be able to run PHPUnit with this command:

```
PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=TestServer"  XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM" vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c YOUPHPUNITXMLCONFIG
```

Set the PHP_IDE_CONFIG corresponding to your settings.

Set breakpoints where you want to stop.

I hope I could help you.

Nico